# VueJS interpolation does not render when Jekyll involved

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, jekyll

For some reason, string interpolation in VueJS is not working as I expect.

This is my HTML:

```
 <ul id='books'>
  <li v-for="row in results.rows">
   <span v-html="row.name"></span> --
   {{ row.name }}
  </li>
 </ul>
```

... and my javascript file...

```
state.elements.bookList = new Vue({
    el: '#books',
    data:{
        db:state.db,
        results:{
            offset:0,
            total_rows:0,
            rows:[
                {name:'bob'},
                {name:'joe'},
            ]
        }
    }
});
```

When this renders, I get the expected two items in the list; however the interpolation does not work. As a test, I added the `v-html` binding, and it **does** render the expected name.

What am I doing wrong that the name does not render?

Comment: [I cannot reproduce this](https://jsfiddle.net/philbrown/p7sxuo42/). Have you perhaps changed the [`delimeters`](https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#delimiters)?

Comment: @Phil That's it. I'm running it through Jekyll which uses handle bars (because everyone does). Jekyll is attempting to resolve the interpolation, and leaving nothing behind for Vue to pick up on. Changing the delimiters actually fixes it.

Comment: I'm actually feeling very Rubber Duckish about having asked this.

Comment: @JeffereyCave I've tagged this with [tag:jekyll] so others can find it. Feel free to add your own answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an issue of conflicting templating engines: `jekyll` and `vuejs`. In both cases, data tags are identified with curly brackets.

In this case, jekyll was resolving the tag to an empty string, later vue coes along and does not find anything.

Other engines that could (easily) conflict:

- Jekyll
- VueJS
- Mustache
- Handlebar

To solve this, one of the template engines will need to have its delimiters changed:

```
state.elements.bookList = new Vue({
    el: '#books',
    delimiters: ['[[', ']]'],
    data:{
        db:state.db,
        results:{
            offset:0,
            total_rows:0,
            rows:[
                {name:'bob'},
                {name:'joe'},
            ]
        }
    }
});


 <ul id='books'>
  <li v-for="row in results.rows">
   <span v-html="row.name"></span> --
   [[ row.name ]]
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 3):

Curly brackets conflict.

If you want jekyll to leave your Vue's brackets alone, you can use the `raw` tag :

`{% raw %}{{ row.name }}{% endraw %}`

Comment: Thank you, this is an elegant answer. I don't really want to change any of the engine's delimiters.